# Using Google Image Recognition to Hide All NSFW Images on Computer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, image-recognition

My goal is to hide all NSFW images on the computer. Is it possible to do this? If it is, how powerful of a computer I would need for this, and can it be done over Google Cloud?

If it is possible, kindly point me in the right direction on how I can learn to do this.

Sorry if this question sounds stupid. My only knowledge of programming is from 6.00.1x and 6.00.2x from MIT. I was checking Google's Image Recognition service and thought that SafeSearch can prove very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? If someone has access to the computer, I'd expect them to have access to the images that are there. Now you could write code to *remove* (or just move) all the images that image recognition thought were "unsafe", but that's not really the same thing.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton By hide, I mean preventing imges from being displayed on the screen even though they are there. I don't think I can 'remove' the images on a web browser. I want to know if I can prevent them from being show on the screen. The same way ad blockers prevent ads from appearing on the screen. Thanks.

Comment: Not with a regular program, no. You'd have to be deeply integrated into the file system or operating system, I think. The detection part isn't the problem - it's the interception.

Comment: @ Daisy Shipton Thank you. Please tell me the level of expertise required to do that (for example, a master's degree in computer science).

Comment: It's not a matter of an academic level of knowledge. You'd need to work out a very concrete set of requirements first, and then that will determine what level of integration you need, and with what. (Just operating system? What about browsers as well, for internet content? What about applications that open images?) Fundamentally this is a very difficult thing to do - so while I can't give any specific level of expertise, I wouldn't suggest taking it on lightly.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton Thank you

Comment: @ Daisy Shipton Thank you